# Exact difference between drag and dragstart event type (?)

Tags: javascript, html

From MDN Documentation I can read:

> Drag - Fired when an element or text selection is being dragged.
>   Dragstart - Fired when the user starts dragging an element or text selection

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API
```

But ... why my function was ignored by browser when I attach it to "drag" event and was perfectly ok when I gave it "dragstart" instead?
From the definition I assume that them both do the same (?)

```
function itemDrag(e) {
e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);  
}


document.getElementById("try1").addEventListener("dragstart",function(){
    itemDrag(event);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The dragstart event is fired when the user starts dragging an element
>   or text selection.
>
> The drag event is fired when an element or text selection is being
>   dragged (every few hundred milliseconds).

So **dragstart** should be fired once, **drag** should be fired continuously.

This comes from the MDN pages.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart

---

### example:

```js
let continu = 0;

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {

     console.log('start');
     
}, false);
  
document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {

  if(continu < 5){
     console.log('continu');
  }
  
  continu ++;
  
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="dropzone">
  <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
    This div is draggable
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

---

Drag related events:

- [`drag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/drag)
- [`dragstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragstart)
- [`dragend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragend)
- [`dragover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragover)
- [`dragenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragenter)
- [`dragleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragleave)
- [`dragexit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragexit)
- [`drop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/drop)

Comment: Thanks a lot Randy !

Comment: I've did it but as my "reputation marks" are too low for now they are unvisible.